# Game authentication like minecraft?

Tags: authentication, minecraft

I'm making a game in C# and was wondering how to authenticate a user. I want it to be similar to minecraft where user makes an account and can pay to make their account premium. People on the team know most languages, so that isn't a limitation. We have a fairly large budget so that isn't a limitation either.

How would I go about doing this?
If you know how to do this and you want to be part of the team just post a comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just within the .NET framework you have multiple options. You could allow impersonation for anonymous access to certain parts of the site and maintain different users for paid accounts (doesn't need to be an AD/whatever user per paid account).

If you don't want to use AD user per account etc. you could write an identity service which passes back a token, allowing your game/site to log the person on as a certain user. If you want claims based identity, you could use the WIF SDK.

If you're happy with AD based basic authentication per user, that's pretty simple. You could pull the user's principles from AD to see if they are in the paid for group etc.

Comment: We just had a discussion...we aren't going to use drm. Completely free game. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: No problems, good luck with your game!